# Focus by default in filter header angular ui grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have gone through the documentation forward and back and I cannot seem to find a way to give the header filter for one of the columns focus when it loads. The user typically filters on the same column every single time. I use these grids for line of business applications and every click or 'tab' saved is 500 saved per person per day.

```
this.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
            { field: 'Order' },
            { field: 'Qty.' }
        ];
```

Then I have the following for the html, so Order gets a filter, but it is not focused by default.

```
<div ui-grid="taskCtrl.gridOptions" ui-grid-selection ui-grid-auto-resize></div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I found out for this problem.

You need to add autofocus to text box of the header filter while creating the column definition.
You can do this by coding something like this:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
enableSorting: true,
columnDefs: [
  { field: 'name' },
  { field: 'company',
    headerCellTemplate: '<div ng-class="{ \'sortable\': sortable }"><div class="ui-grid-vertical-bar">&nbsp;</div><div class="ui-grid-cell-contents" col-index="renderIndex"><span>{{ col.displayName CUSTOM_FILTERS }}</span><span ui-grid-visible="col.sort.direction" ng-class="{ \'ui-grid-icon-up-dir\': col.sort.direction == asc, \'ui-grid-icon-down-dir\': col.sort.direction == desc, \'ui-grid-icon-blank\': !col.sort.direction }">&nbsp;</span></div><div class="ui-grid-column-menu-button" ng-if="grid.options.enableColumnMenus && !col.isRowHeader  && col.colDef.enableColumnMenu !== false" class="ui-grid-column-menu-button" ng-click="toggleMenu($event)"><i class="ui-grid-icon-angle-down">&nbsp;</i></div><div ng-if="filterable" class="ui-grid-filter-container" ng-repeat="colFilter in col.filters"><input type="text" autofocus class="ui-grid-filter-input" ng-model="colFilter.term" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()" ng-attr-placeholder="{{colFilter.placeholder || \'\'}}" /><div class="ui-grid-filter-button" ng-click="colFilter.term = null"><i class="ui-grid-icon-cancel" ng-show="!!colFilter.term">&nbsp;</i> <!-- use !! because angular interprets \'f\' as false --></div></div></div>'
  }
],
onRegisterApi: function( gridApi ) {
  $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
  $scope.gridApi.core.on.sortChanged( $scope, function( grid, sort ) {
    $scope.gridApi.core.notifyDataChange( $scope.gridApi.grid, uiGridConstants.dataChange.COLUMN );
  })
}
```

};

In the above code sample you can see that the headerCellTemplate is being written explicitly. Here is the place you can do the change to get the autofocus. You can do anything you want in this cell template. But be careful not to change any underlying cell template. This may break ui-grid functionality. Hope this helps!

I found the above solution in the below plunker link:
http://plnkr.co/edit/JuDUwpUBwglkDRUYT77g?p=preview