# Set Focus to Control With No Name or ID

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'd like to automatically set the focus on the input control within Angular's ui-grid filter:

[image]

However, that control doesn't have a name or ID. This is what the HTML looks like:

```
<div class="gridFullThin" ui-grid="gridApps" ui-grid-selection ui-grid-resize-columns></div>
```

I tried adding this attribute, but it didn't help:

```
autofocus="autofocus"
```

In IE, within the F12 tools DOM Explorer, I can see that the input looks like this:

```
<input class="ui-grid-filter-input ui-grid-filter-input-0 ng-touched" aria-label="Filter for column" type="text" placeholder="" ng-attr-placeholder="{{colFilter.placeholder || ''}}" ng-model="colFilter.term">
```

It doesn't have an ID. Is there a way I can automatically place focus here?

** EDIT ** - This is the generated HTML as shown in F12 (with the input element highlighted in blue):

[image]

Comment: You can reference it by its class: `document.getElementsByClassName('ui-grid-filter-input-0')[0]` and trigger `.focus()`

Comment: I should note that `autofocus` would work if you were able to put it on the `<input>`'s HTML (but not a parent `div`).

Comment: You may need to check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14837021/44544540)

Comment: You can apparently edit the headerCellTemplate to include the autofocus property on the input elements: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37277401/focus-by-default-in-filter-header-angular-ui-grid

Comment: @JonUleis I did that but the control isn't getting focus. I checked and my variable, element, exists. `var element = document.getElementsByClassName('ui-grid-filter-input-0')[0]; element.focus();`

Comment: You should try to make this query inside a $timeout service.

Comment: It's not working because getElementsByClassName is returning four elements. Grrr.

Comment: This is might be helpful!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833326/how-to-set-focus-on-input-field?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can't edit the markup to add your own ID, you can still target by class or specifying the input as a child of parent with id.

Correct answer as discussed in chat:

```
var elements = document.querySelector('.modal .ui-grid-header-cell .ui-grid-filter-input-0'); 
elements.focus();
```

Comment: I tried getting the elements by class, but I get four of them.

Comment: @BobHorn it's tough to help more without seeing all of the code but you can be more specific when targeting the class. For example if you have one input in header and one in body you can select as 'header input' or in this case, with a class, 'header .ui-grid-filter-input'.

Comment: I just posted a screenshot in my post. Does that help? I just tried this, but it returns 0 elements: `$window.document.getElementsByClassName('ui-grid-header-cell .ui-grid-filter-input-0')`

Comment: @BobHorn try document.getElementsByClassName('ui-grid-header-cell').getElementsByClassName('ui-grid-filter-input-0');

Comment: TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'getElementsByClassName'

Comment: @BobHorn wait, is there more than one input with class of .ui-grid-filter-input-0? It's numbered, which makes me think that could be a good single unique identifier.

Comment: Yes, there are four of them.

Comment: @BobHorn are you also using jquery or no?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131747/discussion-between-serg-chernata-and-bob-horn).

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer that. I have it referenced in my index.html page. But whether I'm actually using Angular code, or jQuery, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

if this is the first input element in your HTML mark-up, then you could do this:

```
document.forms[0].elements[0].focus();
```

otherwise, if you have hidden elements that come before this input, then you would have to loop throught the form elements and find the first non-hidden element.